# Manage Aure database with SSMS 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

As the title says is it actually possible to connect Azure sql database with SSMS and manage (Edit schema and data)? I have managed to connect to the server instance but I am unable to do any modifications. If it is not possible with SSMS is there any other software I could use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noticed when connected to a Windows Azure SQL Database some of the menu items that you're used to are not available, things like "edit top ... Rows" and the table designers.  This means that if you want to make changes like this you're using DDL, so you'll need to brush up on your `ALTER TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` syntax.

I don't know of any other tools that allow you to do this, but I haven't looked very hard.

To answer your next un-asked question of when will MS add this functionality to WASD?  I have no insider knowledge, but I would say don't hold your breath.